# Backbone View events don't get destroyed

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, destroy

I've been having trouble with unbinding view events. I create a view i.e

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events : {
        "click .item"        : "nextPage",
        "scroll"             : "isScrolling",
        "click .zoom"        : "imageZoom"

    },
    initialize : function(){
       this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    onClose : function(){
      ... 
    }
 });

 var view = new myView();
     destroyArray.push(view);
```

once I need to destroy the view I call through my Router a function that loops through the destroy array and calls destroyArray[i].close() (see below) before rendering the next view.

```
    Backbone.View.prototype.close = function(){

    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.$el.removeData().unbind();
    this.remove();
    if (this.onClose){
        this.onClose();
    }
}
```

The close function visibly removes the view from the page but moving back and forth within the views the events (and DOM elements) actually increase. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

When moving between views I re-initialize them i.e.

```
 var view = new myView();
 destroyArray.push(view);
 ...
 view.close();
 ...
 var view1 = new myView1();
 destroyArray.push(view1);
```

I thought that might be causing my problem, but the events that are added do not equal the the number of events bound in the view.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [listenTo](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) method introduced in Backbone 0.9 to help deal with view removals.
You could have :

```
initialize : function(){
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
}

Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
    this.remove();
}
```

Furthermore you don't need to specify the context with this method.

**Edit:** code to look more like the way you did it at first.

Comment: +1 You can also just call this.remove() on a view. That will call stopListening as part of a general clean up.

Comment: I am trying listenTo instead but now I am having trouble triggering events in views i.e. view.trigger("eventname") has this changed?

Comment: Nothing changed concerning the events. Could you post your code where the problem lies ? The object triggering the event and the one listening should be enough.